# I have developed a desktop application using c#. now i need to get all the detail stored in database of desktop application available on webpage

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, web-services

I am new in webservice and my desktop application is almost completed now there is need to show detail of product on webpage that is stored by desktop application. Please tell me how to implement this. Do i need to change existing application.

Comment: is the database stored on the user's computer, or in a central database server on the network?

Comment: data is in user computer but to implement this i can put data on some hosting website

Comment: is it an internal desktop application or public? depending on this and the data being stored, you may need to get customer agreement and comply with data protection laws to use a cloud-based database. can you guarantee the users will have constant internet access if trying to use a remote database? have you fully thought through the ramifications of what you are trying to do?

Comment: You don't need to change anything. Just host your sql server database online and you will be able to access same database from desktop application as well as from your webpage

Comment: It is internal desktop application and user has constant internet application. This desktop application stores the life cycle info of product and now there is need to show this info to public webpage

Comment: oh if that's the case, just host the database on a server in the network, then have a web server which connects to that database and pulls data from it. simples. you might have to change how users pull data onto the application though as the application will change from having a database for each user to a shared database for all users.